# Add UIViewController made via storyboard to TabBarController.setViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I am failing to understand the fundamentals of what is needed to add my HomeViewController (UIViewController) as one of the tabs in my homeTabBarController (UITabBarController) using the setViewControllers method.

I have tried initializing this and simply adding it as a param in the method.  There seems to be a difference between a view controller created via storyboard and one created programmatically because when I tried adding a viewcontroller:UIViewController programmatically to the setViewControllers method, it worked fine.

My code below compiles however I get a runtime exception Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ff7b8491598) at the line when homeTabBarController.setViewControllers is called

`

```
    func loadTabBar() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let homeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeViewController

        homeViewController!.title = "Home"

        homeTabBarController.setViewControllers([homeViewController!], animated: false)
        homeTabBarController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(homeTabBarController, animated: true)
    }
```

`

Comment: Post the complete error message in your question.

Comment: You are using a force unwrap.  Most probably `homeViewController` is `nil` either because a scene with the identifier `Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController` wasn't found or it wasn't an instance of `HomeViewController`.  Change your code to `if let homeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeViewController { ... } else { print("Could not load view controller)}` and see what happens

Comment: it isn't nil.  I have a constants file with identifiers and this represents the identifier associated with HomeViewController.  Also, if you force unwrap something that is nil at runtime, you will get an error that explicitly tells you that it is nil. @Paulw11

Comment: Ok, then if you are going to use a force unwrap you may as well do it one with a forced downcast `let homeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as! HomeViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  //MARK: - Create the instances of ViewControllers
    let grayViewController = HomeViewController()
    let blueViewController = FirstViewController()
    let brownViewController = SecondViewController()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //set title of the viewcontrollers
        grayViewController.title = "home"
        blueViewController.title = "first"
        brownViewController.title = "second"
        
        //Assigne the viewcontrollers to the TabBarViewController
        self.setViewControllers([ grayViewController, blueViewController, brownViewController], animated: false)
        
        //set system images to each tabBars
        guard let items = self.tabBar.items  else {
            return
        }
        
        let images = ["house.fill", "star.fill", "bell.fill"]
        
        for i in 0...2 {
            items[i].image = UIImage(systemName: images[i])
        }
        
        self.tabBar.tintColor = .black
        
    }

// You can download the project from the below github link


https://github.com/ahmetbostanciklioglu/AddingTabBarControllerProgrammatically.git
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the viewcontroller is made via storyboard (this is what I am trying to figure out).  This was noted in my original question @ahmetbostancikli. I also don't understand how to instantiate a viewcontroller that contains a required init?(coder: NSCoder)

Comment: I made this homeviewcontroller via storyboard and then  I assign the homeviewcontroller class to an object, and then I use that object in the setviewcontroller.

Comment: @ahmentbostancikli I've tried this and I still get the same error I've stated in my question.  Is it because I am initializing and doing this work in the viewDidLoad method of HomeViewController and not BEFORE I transition to HomeViewController?

Comment: After looking at your github project, me initializing this in the HomeViewController's viewdidload was exactly my problem. I guess I didn't understand the tabvc needed to be presented and separate from the Homeviewcontroller. Anyways, thank you and I will mark this as the answer! @ahmetbostancikli